# Code First e Campos calculados

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Eu tenho uma classe `Pedido`, que tem um campo calculado, que é o valor do pedido, composto pela somatória dos itens menos o desconto.

```
public class Pedido
{
    public ICollection<PedidoItem> Itens { get; set; }

    public decimal ValorDesconto { get; set; }

    public decimal ValorPedido
    {
        get { return this.Itens.Sum(e => e.Quantidade * e.Valor) - this.ValorDesconto; }
    }
}

public class PedidoItem
{
    public int CodigoProduto { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantidade { get; set; }
}
```

Porém se eu tentar fazer uma query com lambda ou linq filtrando o valor do pedido diretamente, vou obter um erro.

```
// Linq nao reconhece ValorPedido
List<Pedido> pedidos = db.Pedidos.Where(p => p.ValorPedido > x).ToList();
```

Eu poderia fazer:

```
List<Pedido> pedidos = db.Pedidos.ToList().Where(p => p.ValorPedido > x).ToList()
```

Porém essa segunda abordagem irá trazer todos os pedidos do banco de dados para filtrar em memória, o que pode ser ruim para performance.

Eu poderia fazer um Linq, agrupando, e somando, o que geraria uma query mais performática porém eu estaria repetindo a lógica já existente na propriedade ValorPedido da classe `Pedido`.

O Entity 7 é capaz de interpretar `ValorPedido` ou o `ValorPedido` teria que ter um `set`, e minha aplicação alimentar esse atributo(mas há quem diz que não se dever armazenar campos calculados)?

Uma trigger também resolveria, mas eu ficaria preso ao SGBD, por exemplo, não poderia trocar o provider apenas. Há algo a ser feito ou isso é uma limitação da ORM e ponto final?

Comment: Por coincidência eu estava vendo sobre isso hoje. E pelo que eu entendi, você não tem muito o que fazer.

Comment: Veja http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585330/calculated-column-in-ef-code-first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível fazer desta forma, mas alguns cuidados são necessários:

### 1. Informar ao Entity Framework que a propriedade não é mapeada em banco

Se faz assim:

```
[NotMapped]
public decimal ValorPedido
{
    ...
}
```

### 2. Fazer o cálculo apenas quando houver elementos, tratando exceções

```
[NotMapped]
public decimal ValorPedido
{
    get 
    {
        try {
            return this.Itens.Sum(e => e.Quantidade * e.Valor) - this.ValorDesconto;
        } catch {
            throw new Exception("Coleção não inicializada corretamente");
        } 
    }
}
```

A ideia te explicando isso é mostrar o que dá pra fazer, mas isso não significa que seja a forma correta de fazer. A forma correta coloco abaixo.

> Porém se eu tentar fazer uma query com lambda ou linq filtrando o valor do pedido diretamente, vou obter um erro.
>
> ```
> List<Pedido> pedidos = db.Pedidos.Where(p => p.ValorPedido > x).ToList();
> ```

Isto não funciona porque você está misturando lógica de campo mapeado com lógica de campo não mapeado. Precisa ter o seguinte para funcionar:

```
List<Pedido> pedidos = db.Pedidos
                         .Include(p => p.Itens) // Carrego antecipadamente Itens. É equivalente a um JOIN.
                         .AsEnumerable() // Aqui resolvo o select, e o Where abaixo passa a funcionar.
                         .Where(p => p.ValorPedido > x)
                         .ToList();
```

Obviamente isto vai dar algum problema de desempenho dependendo do tamanho das tabelas `Pedidos` e `Itens`. Você pode filtrar com o `Sum()` dentro da consulta assim:

```
List<Pedido> pedidos = db.Pedidos
                         .Include(p => p.Itens) // Carrego antecipadamente Itens. É equivalente a um JOIN.
                         .Where(p => p.Itens.Sum(e => e.Quantidade * e.Valor) > x)
                         .ToList();
```

> O Entity 7 é capaz de interpretar ValorPedido?

Pelo erro, concluímos que não.

> Há algo a ser feito ou isso é uma limitação da ORM e ponto final?

É um problema de abordagem. Você está tentando usar o *framework* de uma maneira não prevista por ele.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. vou pensar melhor na forma que abordo esse tipo de problema com o Entity.

Answer (score 4):

Infelizmente, o que você quer não dá para ser feito desta maneira, porque ao executar um `Where` nos itens do contexto retorna um ICollection, e neste caso os dados só serão trazidos para  a aplicação quando você der um `ToList()` ou selecionar os dados desejados.

Sendo assim quando vc chama o campo calculado diretamente do `IQueryable` ele não consegue calcular porque os dados não estão carregados na memória.

O que vc pode fazer é implementar uma propriedade com o atributo `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` e implementar a lógica no banco de dados.

Vide exemplo no link abaixo:

http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2012/09/23/calculated-columns-in-entity-framework-code-first-migrations.aspx

Comment: que coisa! já pesquisei isso várias vezes, e nunca achei. obrigado

Comment: criando a migração inicial como dita no exemplo, e alterando a coluna que deve ser computada atende minha necessidade de não ter que carregar scripts e rodar nas instalações.

Comment: mas preciso ver o que vou fazer ainda. parece que o campo computado é para campos da própria tabela. O Valor do desconto está na tabela do pedido, porém a somatória dos itens não.De qualquer forma é bem útil essa informação. vou trabalhar em cima dela

Comment: @Murilo Neste caso então, te aconselho a criar uma View para este caso, desta forma além de melhor organizado, ficaria bem mais performático, vide exemplo: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469601.aspx , pense nisto melhor.

Comment: Sim e não. +1 pela abordagem do campo calculado, mas `Itens` não é um `IQueryable<>`: é um `ICollection<>`. Só precisa ser carregado antes para funcionar. Vou colocar uma alternativa.

Comment: Boa Cigano, de toda forma vou editar a resposta para ficar mais completa.